# Maximum of a sequence $\left({n\choose k} \lambda^k\right)_k$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, optimization, binomial-coefficients

Is there an expression for the maximum of a sequence $\left({n\choose k} \lambda^k\right)_k$ (i.e. $\max_{k\in\{0,\ldots,n\}}{n\choose k}\lambda^k)$ in terms of elementary functions of $n$ and $\lambda$?

This seems like a simple calculus problem but my usual method, finding the zero of the derivative, doesn't work here since $n \choose k$ is not differentiable.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that was a typo.  Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In discrete case, it may be useful to look at ratio of successful terms.  Here, let $a_k = \binom{n}k \lambda^k$.  Then:

$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} = \lambda\frac{n-k}{k+1}$$

As $k$ increases from $1$ to $n$, it is easily seen that the numerator decreases and the denominator increases, so the fraction decreases steadily from $\frac{n-1}2$ to $0$.  At some point it becomes less than $1$, and the term before that point would be the maximum.  So we solve for
$$\lambda(n-k) \le k+1 \implies k \ge \frac{n\lambda-1}{\lambda+1}$$

Comment: This is a nice answer, thanks! So, assuming $\lambda>0$, the maximum element is then ${n \choose \lceil n\alpha\rceil}\lambda^{\lceil n\alpha\rceil}$ where $\alpha=\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda+1}$ and the ceiling is taken to the non-negative integer.  I didn't think of taking a "discrete derivative" in this way, and will add it to my toolbox.

Comment: Actually, with $k^* = \lceil\frac{n\lambda-1}{\lambda+1}\rceil$, if $1\le k^*\le n$, the maximal element would be $a_{k^*}=\binom{n}{k^*} \lambda^{k^*}$.

Comment: Argh, yes, of course!  I forgot to put a factor of $n$ in my definition of $\alpha$, which should be $\alpha=\frac{\lambda-1/n}{\lambda+1}$.  This illustrates that as $n$ gets large $\alpha\approx\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+1}$ and gets us nice information theoretic (entropy-based) bounds on maximal $a_{k^*}$...